# How to Convert Twitter Timestamp to DateTime?

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, twitter

I've been googling this for some time now, but I could never find an answer to my problem.

I'm making a Twitter client using C# and Windows Presentation Foundation, and I can't figure out how to change the timestamps that Twitter supplies to a DateTime or UNIX timestamp.

I know it's possible with Regex, but I never found a solution.

Is there some easy way to do this that I'm unaware of? The Twitter timestamp format that I'm trying to convert from looks like this:

```
Fri Feb 11 23:45:15 +0000 2011
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on a [sample elsewhere](http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2009/05/twitter-date-parsing-in-c/), how about using the [ParseExact method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
const string format = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy";
my_date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
DateTimeOffset timestamp;
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(
    "Fri Feb 11 23:45:15 +0000 2011",
    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss K yyyy",
    null,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out timestamp))
  ; // use timestamp
```

This assumes:

- The current culture is the correct one to use (e.g., "Fri", "Feb", etc.)
- Dates, hours, minutes, and seconds are 0-filled (e.g., "Fri Feb 04 02:05:02 +0000 2011")

Comment: +1 Even better to include a culture that has the correct days of week in them ;-)