# delphi how to convert twitter timestamp to TDatetime

Tags: delphi, twitter, delphi-2009, formatdatetime

In continue to this question:
[How to Convert Twitter Timestamp to DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975236/how-to-convert-twitter-timestamp-to-datetime)

what is the code to convert twitter date time stamp to TDateTime?

edit:
StrDateTime(const string;TFormatSettings);

could handle some of it,
now only to figure out how to intoduce new format.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us some code or update youre question to be more specific. What parts of the conversion are you having problems with?

Comment: i pretty much gave up on using TFormatSettings, as it raised errors, and could not find a way to produce out the dates. so i just parsed the text as the answer showed and presented it in an imperfect way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since we don't have the ParseExact function, you need to parse the components of the timestamp positionally. You could do it with the Copy() function.  ex:

```
TheMonthAsString := Copy(TwitterDate,5,3);
TheDayAsString := Copy(TwitterDate,9,2);
etc..
```

Convert those pieces to Integers, and then you can use EncodeDateTime (in the DateUtils unit) (Thanks Jens!) to generate a TDateTime.

Summary:  Pick the string apart into the individual components of the timestamp, and convert that to a TDateTime using EncodeDateTime or StrToDateTime.

Comment: Jens - agreed.  Somehow I forgot about that function.

Comment: This is a delphi-2009 question. There is no encodeDateTime in delphi2009. there is encodeDate and EncodeTime.

Comment: I'm using D2005 right now, and it's got EncodeDateTime and DecodeDateTime, in the DateUtils unit.  Maybe you don't have DateUtils in your 'uses' clause?